# Laravel $request doesn't contain some input-array form fields

Tags: php, arrays, input, request, laravel-5.4

I have a form in laravel 5.4 allowing people to create questionnaires - adding question fields dynamically (this is handled elsewhere in js).

```
<form method="POST" action="/questions" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="featured-img">Featured Image</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="featured-image image-uploader" id="featured-img" name="featured_img" />
        <img src="" class="image-preview" alt="uploaded image preview" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input name="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="skill_level">Skill Level</label>
        <select name="skill_level" class="custom-select" id="skill_level" required>
            <option value="kids">Kids</option>
            <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
            <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
            <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="add-contributor-container">
        <button id="add-contributor">Add contributor</button>
    </div>

    <div id="contributor-section">

        <div class="form-group contributors">
            <label for="contributors-1">Contributor 1</label>
            <input name="contributors[1]" class="form-control contributor-name" id="contributors-1" required />
            <input name="contributors_amount[1]" class="form-control contributor-amount" id="contributors-amount-1" required />
            <button type="button" class="remove-contributor">Remove Contributor</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select name="category_id" class="form-control" id="category" required>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="add-question-container">
        <button type="button" id="add-question">Add question</button>
    </div>

    <div id="question-section">

        <div class="form-group question">
            <label for="questions-1">Question 1</label>
            <textarea name="questions[1]" class="form-control question-content" id="questions-1" rows="3" required></textarea>
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="questions-image image-uploader" name="questions_img[1]" />
            <img src="" class="image-preview" alt="uploaded image preview" />
            <button type="button" class="remove-question">Remove Question</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="published">Publish</label>
        <p>If unticked, only you will be able to see this project. You can edit this later.</p>
        <input name="published" type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="published" value="1" checked="checked">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="order" />

    <div class="form-group">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

When I retrieve the Request in my controller it contains all my form data ( including the array of contributors so I assume my input array syntax is correct ) but **the questions_img array is missing**.

Is there something I'm missing as to **why just this one** field wouldn't be getting sent?
Here is how I am checking the Request in my controller:

```
public function store( StoreProject $request )
{ 
   dd( $request ); 
}
```

And StoreProject is a FormRequest I have created (which may be the main culprit):

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
```

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreProject extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    $rules = [

        'title' => 'required',

        'category_id' => 'required',

        'description' => 'required',

        'order' => 'required',

        'featured_img' => 'image',

        'skill_level' => 'required|string'

    ];

    foreach( $this->request->get( 'questions_img' ) as $key => $val )
    {

        $rules['questions_img.'.$key] = 'image';

    }

    return $rules;

}
```

}

So to summarise: If I use the normal **Request** instead of **StoreProject** in the store function and call **$request->all(**) the field is passed through correctly. Is there a reason why $request would be missing fields if I have used a custom Form Request?

Comment: In laravel file inputs are accessed by doing `$request->file('name')`. have you tried that? Also try changing the name array to `questions_img[]` instead of `questions_img[1]`

Comment: just try to comment all inputs , and test only 'questions_img[1]'  file is receiving on server side or not , please check it ?

Comment: check the result by:  dd($request->all()) ;

Comment: Thank for your advice. Having followed these steps I realised this is something to do with using a custom Form Request instead of the normal Request ( I have just updated the question to include this - apologies ). Not sure if this gives any further clues?